# How to set data-* attribute of checked radio to class of another element using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, custom-data-attribute

How do I take the `data-attribute` of a checked radio button and output it inside the class attribute of a different element?

Please take a look at the example:

```css
body{
  background: #eee;
}  

.box{
  background: #000;
  margin: 40px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.box.black{
  background: #000;
}

.box.white{
  background: #fff;
}

.box.green{
  background: #00d300;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input data-color="black" id="radio1" type="radio" name="radio" checked>
<label for="radio1">Black</label>
<input data-color="white" id="radio2" type="radio" name="radio">
<label for="radio2">White</label>
<input data-color="green" id="radio3" type="radio" name="radio">
<label for="radio3">Green</label>

<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Where's the jQuery you tried which doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using CSS only. [`:checked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked) select checked radio and `~` is [General sibling selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors).

```css
input[data-color="black"]:checked ~ .box {
    background: #000;
}
```

```css
.box{
  background: #000;
  margin: 40px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

input[data-color="black"]:checked ~ .box {
  background: #000;
}

input[data-color="white"]:checked ~ .box {
  background: #fff;
}

input[data-color="green"]:checked ~ .box {
  background: #00d300;
}
```

```html
<input data-color="black" id="radio1" type="radio" name="radio" checked>
<label for="radio1">Black</label>
<input data-color="white" id="radio2" type="radio" name="radio">
<label for="radio2">White</label>
<input data-color="green" id="radio3" type="radio" name="radio">
<label for="radio3">Green</label>

<div class="box"></div>
```

If you want to do it using jquery, you need to get value of `data-color` attribute using [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) or [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) and set it to class of `.box` using [`.addClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/).

```
$("input[name='radio']").change(function(){
    $(".box").removeClass().addClass("box " + $(this).attr("data-color"));
});
```

```js
$("input[name='radio']").change(function(){
    $(".box").removeClass().addClass("box " + $(this).attr("data-color"));
});
```

```css
.box{
  background: #000;
  margin: 40px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.box.black{
  background: #000;
}

.box.white{
  background: #fff;
}

.box.green{
  background: #00d300;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input data-color="black" id="radio1" type="radio" name="radio" checked>
<label for="radio1">Black</label>
<input data-color="white" id="radio2" type="radio" name="radio">
<label for="radio2">White</label>
<input data-color="green" id="radio3" type="radio" name="radio">
<label for="radio3">Green</label>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Please don't provide an answer until the OP has demonstrated that they've actually tried something.